# Handle Time Baseline using Statistical approach

Tags: sas, statistics

I want to perform an analysis on average handle time (AHT) from a population and come up with a baseline which can be set as a goal.

AHT: The total time taken to resolve a specific task.

Sample Table:

task    aht_in_seconds
123 2
234 10
456 20
678 5
789 3000
454 47867
213 6
998 60
547 135
565 776
325 342
567 223
565 334
666 360

As per my analysis, I am taking the mean and standard deviation of the population and trying to remove the outliers by using Z-score and box zenkin method.

As per Z-score (x-mean/sigma) method (-2 to +2 range (95%)) the standard deviation comes very high even after removing outliers.

Box-zenkin method: (for outlier removal)

lower limit: Q1-1.5*Interquartile Range 
Upper limit: Q3+1.5*Interquartile Range

(Interquartile Range is derived by SAS Univariate)

As per the box-zenkin method, the SD is minimal but the final AHT value does not look realistic i.e very low as 150 seconds whereas the time & motion study gives a higer value of 250 seconds for a task

I am wondering if my methods are correct or missing something. Are there any other methods to remove outliers and perform the same analysis. Any guidance would be a great help.

Comment: This isn't a SO question, possibly it belongs on stats.stackexchange.com.  You shouldn't necessarily remove outliers. They're part of your population.

Comment: Thank you foe your response. Since this is a baseline, I will have to remove outliers or else the final number (lets say 70th percentile)  will be completely skewed.

Comment: Since the term outliers doesn't have a fixed definition this is a methods question, not a programming question.